# How to get all google sheet tab name from a public sheet without app script

Tags: json, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

I am able to parse JSON data from https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1AtYF5g2_A3AiAhejVj595bDLxO1zoGq7PNGjbdV9U8Q/od6/public/values?alt=json this way.

Is there any similar way to get all the sheet tab name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your endpoint is used for Sheets API v3. But the Google Sheets v3 API will be shut down on June 8, 2021. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3) So I would like to propose to use Sheets API v4.

When the Spreadsheet is publicly shared, the information of the Spreadsheet can be retrieved by the method of "spreadsheets.get" of Sheets API v4. But, in the current stage, in order to use Sheets API, API key is required to be used. When API key is not used, an error like `The request is missing a valid API key.` occurs. So please be careful this.

When you retrieve your API key, you can retrieve the sheet names of the publicly shared Spreadsheet with the following endpoint.

#### Endpoint:

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1AtYF5g2_A3AiAhejVj595bDLxO1zoGq7PNGjbdV9U8Q?fields=sheets(properties(title%2CsheetId))&key={your API key}
```

- In this case, you can also access to above endpoint using the browser because of GET method.

#### Result:

When above endpoint is requested, the following value is obtained.

```
{
  "sheets": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "sheetId": 0,
        "title": "Sheet1"
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "sheetId": 12345,
        "title": "Sheet2"
      }
    },
    ,
    ,
    ,
  ]
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

Comment: Hi, Many many thanks..Your Endpoint works!!...But i want to know- if i want to get these data ignoring "(" first bracket in "(properties(title%2CsheetId))" here. Is it possible?@Tanaike

Comment: @Shihab365 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, in that case, how about using `sheets.properties.title` as the fields? It's like `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}?fields=sheets.properties.title&key={APIkey}`. Or, when you want to retrieve both the sheet names and sheet IDs, how about `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}?fields=sheets.properties.title,sheets.properties.sheetId&key={APIkey}`? If I misunderstood your additional question, I apologize.

Comment: @Shihab365 By the way, in order to retrieve both sheet names and sheet IDs, you can also use `fields=sheets.properties(title,sheetId)` as the fields.

Comment: It's perfectly working!!!..You are really helpful...Can you tell me using this Endpoint("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}?fields=sheets.properties.title&key={APIkey}") how i get title in JSON format like this structure, {"sheets":[
   {"title":"Sheet1"},
   {"title":"Sheet2"}
]} @Tanaike

Comment: @Shihab365 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your 2nd question was also resolved. About your 3rd question, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your 3rd question. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your all questions. I think that I have to study more. So, in this case, I would like to recommend to post your 3rd question as new question. By this, it will help users think of the solution. When you can cooperate to resolve your 3rd question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I asked you in my last question,kindly answer if you know. How to get in specific sheet data, similar to get title endpoint?..Suppose in my google sheet contains a sheet tab name "profile". And profile contains labels,'name','phone'. How to get these data? @Tanaike

Comment: @Shihab365 Thank you for replying. About your 4th question, I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Thank you for your helpful mind. This is my details question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67241767/how-to-convert-or-retrieve-google-sheet-api-v4-data-into-json-format". If you solve this, it will be very help for me. @Tanaike

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the Google Drive API v4 endpoint with the fields limited:
`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID}?fields=properties(title)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

The fields limits the answer to only what you want, so you don't download data that you won't use anyways.

The result should look like this:

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "title": "{YOUR_SPREADSHEET_TITLE}"
  }
}
```

You can play with it on [Google API explorer](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22spreadsheetId%22%3A%22YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22properties(title)%22%7D) before actually using it in your code.

### References

- [Spreadhseets.get (Google Drive API reference)](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)