# How to retrieve google sheet api v4 data into JSON format

Tags: json, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am able to parse data from google sheet api v4. Here is retrieve sheet data.

Sample:

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1vW-N2WRchAmxd8-isEx4oPpJourPsIIavqfvT_Nbtzw/values/Master?key=AIzaSyAwaXGDfOOdUX-YaGIn0S8Q7ae-ONC_cLs
```

But i want to retrive these data in below json format

#### Sample JSON format that i want to achieve:

```
{"values":[

{"Timestamp":"2021-03-09", "Student ID-Name":"", "Umail":"shihabcse@gmail.com", "Geoloc-Latitude":"", "Geoloc-Longitude":"", "Subject-Code":"PHY4101"},

{"Timestamp":"2021-03-09", "Student ID-Name":"", "Umail":"shihabcse@gmail.com", "Geoloc-Latitude":"", "Geoloc-Longitude":"", "Subject-Code":"MATH4103"},

{"Timestamp":"2021-04-13", "Student ID-Name":"", "Umail":"shihabcse@gmail.com", "Geoloc-Latitude":"", "Geoloc-Longitude":"", "Subject-Code":"HUM4105"}

]}
```

If anyone solve this, it's huge help for me...TIA

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Actually i want to achieve this without app script. @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From `Actually i want to achieve this without app script.`, I couldn't notice you don't want to use Google Apps Script as a workaround. In this case, I understood that my answer was not useful for your situation. So, I would like to delete my answer. I deeply apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: I believe your skill is not poor. Please help me to solve my problem. I want to an Endpoint url which is generate output in above sample format. @Tanaike

Comment: There is NO endpoint url like you want. So you have to transform your datarange by yourself with the mean of a script. There is no other alternative, except writting a javascript inside an html page.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this `https://opensheet.vercel.app/id/range`

1. From this `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1vW-N2WRchAmxd8-isEx4oPpJourPsIIavqfvT_Nbtzw/values/Master?key=AIzaSyAwaXGDfOOdUX-YaGIn0S8Q7ae-ONC_cLs` you can get the ID and range.
2. copy this range [image: range]
3. copy your sheet id `1vW-N2WRchAmxd8-isEx4oPpJourPsIIavqfvT_Nbtzw`
4. And then combine all `https://opensheet.vercel.app/1vW-N2WRchAmxd8-isEx4oPpJourPsIIavqfvT_Nbtzw/Master!A1:Z14989`
5. the results will be like this [link](https://opensheet.vercel.app/1vW-N2WRchAmxd8-isEx4oPpJourPsIIavqfvT_Nbtzw/Master!A1:Z14989) [image]

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Fire up Google Spreadsheet and enter your data.
Generate a shareable link and switch to "Anyone with the link on the internet can View."
Copy the link to your clipboard.
Step 3:
Type [sheet.best] on the browser and click on the +Connect button.
Step 4:
On the Connection URL section, paste the Spreadsheet URL.

#JSON #Google Sheet #API

Specify the origin into Google Spreadsheet.
Step 5:
Tap on the Connect option, and there you go! A brand new REST API in the Connection URL.
Step 6:
Copy the API or Connection URL into your clipboard.
Step 7:
Paste it on the browser, and experience the spreadsheet data in JSON format!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function table2json() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Master');
  var [headers, ...rows] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var data = {}
  var items = []
  rows.forEach(function(r) {
    var obj={}
    r.forEach(function (c, j) {
      obj[headers[j]] = c
    })
    items.push(obj)
  })
  data['values'] = items
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(data))
}
```

you will get a json that represents your datarange